# delete and then insert object Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have this method that delete object if exist and insert the new instance any way :

```
  internal void SaveCarAccident(WcfContracts.BLObjects.Contract.Dtos.CarAccident DTOCarAccident)
    {                       
         using(var context = BLObjectsFactory.Create())
        {
            context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            CarAccident NewCarAccident = ConvertToCarAccident(DTOCarAccident);
            CarAccident carFromDB = context.CarAccident.FirstOrDefault(current => current.CarAccidentKey.Equals(NewCarAccident.CarAccidentKey));
            if(carFromDB != null)
                context.CarAccident.DeleteObject(carFromDB);
            context.CarAccident.AddObject(NewCarAccident);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I sometimes get exception that the key already exist in table.
I wnted to know if the way I save the changes is a problem (saving after delete and insert and not after each one)
At the time I got the exception there were few clients that activate the method at the same time I blocked other clients from writing already, but is this may be the problem ?
Thanks
Eran

Comment: Why do you delete and recreate, instead of updating ?

Comment: this is the requirement I recieved , anyway I'm not looking for the technical problem solution here but to understand the way that save changes work in this case